# Calling a function on the set method of a property in C# throws System.StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

New to c#. Here is the sample of the json I am working with. The objective is to have the two letter flag code converted to a flag emoji.

```
[
    {
      "name": "American Samoa",
      "flag": "",
      "code": "AS",
      "dialcode": "+1684"
    },
    {
      "name": "Andorra",
      "flag": "",
      "code": "AD",
      "dialcode": "+376"
    },
]
```

I have this code below which converts the two letter country code from a json file to a flag emoji. I am calling a method which actually does the conversion on the set method of the Flag property. Running this code throws a System.StackOverflowException.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
    
namespace Bol.Models
{
    internal class Countries
    {
        public List<Country> CountriesInfo { get; set; }
        public Countries()
        {
            StreamReader r = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\folder\\Desktop\\Bol\\Bol\\Resources\\Data\\Countries.json");
            string jsonString = r.ReadToEnd();
            CountriesInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Country>>(jsonString);           
        }
        
    }

    internal class Country
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Flag { get { return Flag; } set { Flag = IsoCountryCodeToFlagEmoji(value); } }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Dialcode { get; set; }

        public string IsoCountryCodeToFlagEmoji(string countryCode) => string.Concat(countryCode.ToUpper().Select(x => char.ConvertFromUtf32(x + 0x1F1A5)));
    }  
}
```

Comment: To set `Flag`, you must first set `Flag`, and to set `Flag`, you must first set `Flag`. Do you see the problem here?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar I dont understand what you meant.

Comment: You're referencing the same property from itself. You're creating an infinite loop.

Comment: If you don't use auto-properties ie. `{get;set;}` you need to define your own fields to accommodate those properties. Make a new `private string _flag;` field that will underlie your `Flag` property

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Isn' t that what I am doing with the other properties as well?

Comment: No, they are autoimplemented properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
public string Flag
{
    get { return Flag; }
    set { Flag = IsoCountryCodeToFlagEmoji(value); }
}
```

Let's look at your code here.

- `get`: The call to get the value of `Flag` will have to call to get the value of the `Flag` property, which will call to get the value of the `Flag` property in an infinite loop.
- `set`: The call to set the value of `Flag` will try and assign a value to the `Flag` property, which will try to assign a value to the `Flag` property in an infinite loop.

You need a backing field for this.

```cs
private string _flag;

public string Flag
{
    get { return _flag; }
    set { _flag = IsoCountryCodeToFlagEmoji(value); }
}
```

I'd suggest perhaps having two properties though, because the `Flag` property is currently transforming the value you input, so that what you `get` is not what you `set`. You could have one for country code, and one for flag:

```cs
private string _countryCode;

public string CountryCode
{
    get { return _countryCode; }
    set
    {
        _countryCode = value;
        Flag = IsoCountryCodeToFlagEmoji(value);
    }
}

public string Flag { get; private set; }
```

This calculates `Flag` at the time `CountryCode` is set. Alternatively, you could calculate it every time `Flag` is accessed:

```cs
public string CountryCode { get; set; }
public string Flag { get { return IsoCountryCodeToFlagEmoji(CountryCode); } }
// or public string Flag => IsoCountryCodeToFlagEmoji(CountryCode);
```

---

Re your question "isn't what what I'm doing with the other properties as well?": no it isn't.

When compiled, `public string Name { get; set; }` becomes something like this:

```cs
[CompilerGenerated]
[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
private string <Name>k__BackingField;

public string Name
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    get
    {
        return <Name>k__BackingField;
    }
    [CompilerGenerated]
    set
    {
        <Name>k__BackingField = value;
    }
}
```

Notice how it has a separate backing field? Now let's compare that to what your `Flag` property gets compiled as:

```cs
public string Flag
{
    get
    {
        return Flag;
    }
    set
    {
        Flag = IsoCountryCodeToFlagEmoji(value);
    }
}
```

Notice how there's no backing field?

You can see the compiled (and then decompiled, since C# is compiled to intermediate language) version [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQAdYwggdsgZgBoATEAagB8ABAJgEYBYAKGoAYACa+gOgBkAlrgCOAbhbUCXWhwDCHAN4sOKrlO6cAclAC2ERRwDmEGKI7ITZgL7LVkrvU4AxADZRDB4zAPUA7B1d3a3MTA0CPAF4OAElkAHtZOLhcGAQAT0SSCAAVOPCAUR04gCsBAAoANygXOAgASmCbZlU1B05YhKSU9MycvLdDQpLyjQ4AYy7UjLisuo4IgD42nkTcMdgyieSp3p5cgFV0dBwyup4AZQgXCDGYMoAPeaWxgAsoBBW43AqcGCcEOI6fYwMAEWgPDjkDhse70Jz0ACCAFY6qjxMwrEA)

Note that member names with `<` and `>` are valid in IL but not in C#, so the compiler's code generation uses these to avoid conflicts with code you write.

Comment: @Sumchans I've addressed your question from the comments about autoproperties vs what you wrote. If my answer has solved your problem, feel free to accept it using the checkmark on the left-hand side.

Comment: Will surely do. That was super quick, will have to wait 6 minutes to accept it as an answer.